# Function returning error on call

Tags: php, mysql, function, arguments

I am creating a script that pulls a menu from a database. I am currently separating the menu in to 6 separate categories. Rather than create a query for each category and fetching every result, I'd like to create a function that identifies the category and then post the correct results. Currently, my function is returning the error, "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/a2077073/public_html/functions.php on line 5". I don't have much experience with functions and searching yielded no results. Code is posted below.

```
<?php 
function getmenuitems($menu) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM `menu` WHERE `item_cat`= '" .$menu. "' ";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);


    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $item_name = stripslashes($row['item_name']);
        $item_des = stripslashes($row['item_des']);
        $item_price = stripslashes($row['item_price']);     
     ?>
<div class="menu_contain">
  <div class="order-menu-first">
    <div class="mp"><strong><?php echo $item_name; ?></strong> <?php echo $item_des; ?>        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-menu-second">
    <div class="mp">
      <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-menu-third">
    <div class="mp">
      <input type="text" value="notes">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-menu-third">
    <div class="mp"> <?php echo $item_price; ?> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-menu-fifth">
    <div class="mp"> <a href="#">X</a> </div>
  </div><div class="clear"></div>
```

and I am calling the function with,

```
  <?php 
echo getmenuitems('firsts');
   ?>
```

Comment: `code`  <?php
   } }
     else {
  echo 'NO RESULTS'; 
     }} ?>

Comment: is located at the end of the first script, I just could not figure out how to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$mysqli` is not defined inside the function scope. Particularly the error is triggered when calling `$mysqli->query($query);`. `$mysqli` is not even defined in the global file scope. At this point you have three main options:

1. Create a mysqli connection in the global scope and pass it as second (or first) parameter: `function getmenuitems($mysqli, $menu) {`
2. **Not suggested**: create `$mysqli` inside the function itself.
3. **Really not suggested**: Create a mysqli connection in the global scope and use `global $mysqli;` to access it inside the function.

Comment: Thanks - I forgot that I needed to include the connection in the function.